# How to remove the duplicate record in oracle query

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle11g

Table 1:

```
ID  CODE_ID
123  1010
234  1415
```

Table 2:

```
ID STATE CODE_ID
123  9   1010
123  13  1010
234  20  1415
234  30  1410
```

My query:

```
select a.ID, b.STATE, b.CODE_ID
from Table1 a, Table2 b
where a.ID = b.ID 
and a.CODE_ID = b.CODE_ID
```

Current query results:

```
ID STATE CODE_ID
123  9   1010
123  13  1010
234  20  1415    --------record dont want to see in result.
```

my expected results

```
ID STATE CODE_ID
123  9   1010
123  13  1010
```

Could you pls looks what should i do to remove that one records from my query

Comment: I'm not sure which row you want to remove, nor which RDBMS you're using.

Comment: i put comment with the records i dont want to see becasuse ID 234 has two CODE_ID's and both of CODE_ID's doesnt exist in Table1

Comment: that's not true, the code_id 1415 does exist in table 1 and in table 2?

Comment: Agree yes it exists in both table but For each ID there are two CODE, but i want to see either both or none

Comment: or lets make it simple..Just look table1 and table 2 and my expected results. how to get those results.

Comment: What if there are 3 states per code_id in table2?

Comment: Yes its possible but we dont have any concern with States only looking ID and Codes

Comment: @Qasim0787 right, but I'm trying to determine what the logic is; is it just the case where you have two rows per code_id that you're after? Or where you have more than one row per code_id? Or something else?

Comment: @Qasim0787 also, what if there was a second row with code_id = 1415, but a different id? (eg. 123) Would you expect to see both 1415 rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an another way using analytics ...

```
  with Table1 as (
           select 123 id, 1010 code_id from dual union all
           select 234 id, 1415 code_id from dual 
           ),
        Table2 as (
           select 123 id, 9  state, 1010 code_id from dual union all
           select 123 id, 13 state, 1010 code_id from dual union all
           select 234 id, 20 state, 1415 code_id from dual union all
           select 234 id, 20 state, 1415 code_id from dual union all
           select 234 id, 20 state, 1410 code_id from dual union all
           select 234 id, 30 state, 1410 code_id from dual 
           ),
     w_sub as (
        select a.id aid, b.ID  bid, b.STATE, b.CODE_ID,
              count(a.id) over (partition by b.id) chk,
              count(*) over (partition by b.id) chkt
        from Table2 b
           left outer join
              Table1 a
              on a.ID = b.ID 
              and a.CODE_ID = b.CODE_ID
        )
  select bid  id, state, code_id
    from w_sub
   where chk = chkt
  /

          ID      STATE    CODE_ID
  ---------- ---------- ----------
         123         13       1010
         123          9       1010
```

Comment: Table1 and Table2 are huge tables, I cant write them like this                          select 123 id, 9  state, 1010 code_id from dual union all
           select 123 id, 13 state, 1010 code_id from dual union all
           select 234 id, 20 state, 1415 code_id from dual union all
           select 234 id, 20 state, 1415 code_id from dual union all
           select 234 id, 20 state, 1410 code_id from dual union all
           select 234 id, 30 state, 1410 code_id from dual

Comment: got it perfect you are genius

Comment: Yeah, the "with" clauses are just there to mimic your tables ... you'd strip those out and keep just the w_sub and main query .. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative using analytic functions, assuming you're after rows in t2 that have more than 1 row per id and code_id:

```
select id,
       state,
       code_id
from   (select t2.id,
               t2.state,
               t2.code_id,
               count(*) over (partition by t2.id, t2.code_id) cnt
        from   table1 t1
               inner join table2 t2 on (t1.id = t2.id
                                        and t1.code_id = t2.code_id))
where  cnt > 1;
```

If you're after rows where there are only two rows per id and code_id, then use `where cnt = 2` instead.

If you're after multiple rows with *different* states then replace `count(*)` with `count(distinct t2.state)` (e.g., if there are two rows for an id and code_id but both have the same state, and you want to exclude that case).

Comment: Yeah, this is what I came up with ... Only 1 subtle difference, I didn't assume 2 rows :) but small issue there, since OP seems to indicate 2 rows ... ;)

Comment: I didn't assume 2 rows either? My query has "more than 1 row per id and code_id", not "two rows per id and code_id"

Comment: Ahh, didn't see your partition by "t2.code_id" .. that's different from what I used ... Let me post mine then ... because ours behaves differently for example data:  ID: 234, and 4 rows: CODE_ID: 1415, 1415, 1410, 1410 ... ;)  That's what I meant by not assuming 2 rows .. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.ID, b.STATE, b.CODE_ID
FROM Table1 a, Table2 b
WHERE 
    a.ID = b.ID 
    AND a.CODE_ID = b.CODE_ID
    AND a.CODE_ID IN
(
    SELECT CODE_ID FROM Table2 
    GROUP BY CODE_ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: And also remember the point Mr. Boneist raised. If you don't want to display the records greater than 2 the replace the line **HAVING COUNT(*) > 1** with this: **HAVING COUNT(*) = 2** OR you can do whatever check here at this line